# How to iterate over consecutive elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm looking for a method that is similar to `Array#combination`, but the order matters.

Given this input:

```
array = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

I'd like to get:

```
[['a','b','c'],['b','c','d'],['c','d','e']]
```

I'm trying to find the method that does this:

```
array = ['a','b','c','d','e']
x,a = 3,[] 

until x > (ary.size) do 
  a += (0.upto(ary.size - x).map{|i|  ary[i..(x-1)+i]} )
  x += 1 
end
```

Comment: Did you read the Array and Enumerable documentation?

Comment: I only looked through Arrray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Enumerable documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html) is your friend:

```
array = ['a','b','c','d','e']
array.each_cons(3).to_a
# => [["a", "b", "c"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["c", "d", "e"]]
```

[`each_cons(n) { ... }`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)

> Iterates the given block for each array of consecutive  elements. If no block is given, returns an enumerator.

Comment: ah i see i was only looking in Array